# Excel: how to create multiple rows from one

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have many rows in a document in which I need to insert a certain subset of rows with others. In particular, I need one row for each month considered. If I have the row starting with July and finishing with September, I need to replace that row with 3 rows, one for July, one for August and one for September.

How can I do it automatically?

[image: Before and After]

Comment: I can think of a few ways of doing this - but I am not sure of what you mean (or expect) by "do it automatically". Do you mean at data entry time, by a user, or an administrator in bulk once? Would it be acceptable to be a button in a ribbon that runs a macro/VBA that does this? On one line or the whole sheet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that your data look like this:

[image]
<sub>(1) I formatted columns `E` and `F` as `mmm-yy (m/yyyy)`
to avoid language-based confusion.</sub>
<sup>(2) There is a copyable version of the above in [this answer’s source](https://superuser.com/revisions/6c0a60b4-37c1-4114-9c9a-9e7031b814e0/view-source).</sup>

on `Sheet1`,
and that you want to copy it to `Sheet2` with the extra rows added. 
You can do that with three “helper columns” on `Sheet2` —
in the below steps, I use `X`, `Y`, and `Z`.  Here’s how to do it:

- Copy the column headings from `Sheet1`, row 1, to `Sheet2`, row 1.
- Enter `=IF($Y2=0, INDEX(Sheet1!A:A, $X2), "")` into `Sheet2!A2`
  and drag/fill to the right to cover all your data (i.e., to column `I`).
- Copy `Sheet1:A2:I2` and paste formats onto `Sheet2:A2:I2`.
- Change `Sheet2!E2` (begin month) to
      `=DATE(YEAR(INDEX(Sheet1!E:E, X2)), MONTH(INDEX(Sheet1!E:E, X2))+Y2, 1)`.
- Enter `2` in `Sheet2!X2`. 
  This designates the row on `Sheet1` that *this* row (on `Sheet2`)
  will pull data from, so, for example, if your data actually begin
  in row 61 on `Sheet1`, enter `61` in `Sheet2!X2`.
- Enter `0` in `Sheet2!Y2`.
- Enter `=INDEX(Sheet1!F:F, $X2)` into `Sheet2!Z2`. 
  (If you want, format it as a date.)
- Select `Sheet2!A2:Z2` and drag/fill down to row 3.
- Change `Sheet2!X3` to `=IF(E2<Z2, X2, X2+1)`.
- Change `Sheet2!Y3` to `=IF(E2<Z2, Y2+1, 0)`.
- Select `Sheet2!A3:Z3` and drag/fill down as far as you need
  to get all your data.

It should look something like this:

[image]

Notes:

- As stated in the instructions, `Sheet2!Xn` specifies
  the row on `Sheet1` that row *`n`* (on `Sheet2`) will pull data from.
- `Sheet2!Yn` is a one-up number
  within a `Sheet2!Xn` value; i.e., within a `Sheet1` row. 
  For example, since rows 3-6 on `Sheet2` pull data from`Sheet1` row 3,
  we have `X3`=`X4`=`X5`=`X6`=3, and `Y3`, `Y4`, `Y5`, `Y6` = 0, 1, 2, 3.
- Column `Z` is just the “true” branch of the `IF` expression in column `F`;
  i.e., the end month for this group of rows.

Of course you can hide columns `X`, `Y`, and `Z`. 
Or, if you want to do this just once and be done, you can copy and paste values.