# Excel 2013: Convert row into two rows and edits both rows

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, microsoft-excel-2013

I'd like to write (copy) a module that converts certain rows into two rows and edits the original row. For example, I'd like to convert this:

```
6/1/2015    16:25    1:00
```

to this:

```
6/1/2015    16:25    23:59
6/2/2015    0:00     1:00
```

I've identified the rows I'd like to do this to in another column. And there are other columns in the rows that I'd like to simply copy down.

I'd appreciate any help and/or VBA tutorials you recommend to get me to a point where I could write this on my own.

[image]

Comment: Have you searched the web for VBA tutorials?

Comment: Use Excel VBA help trying to read this [simple macro](http://superuser.com/q/997373/458082), maybe you can readapt it.

Answer (score 2):

This code should help:

```
Public Sub splittime()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    firstrow = 2
    firstcopycolumn = 4
    lastcopycolumn = 7
    sheetname = "Sheet1"
    Dim wkb As Workbook
    Dim wks As Worksheet
    Set wkb = ThisWorkbook
    Set wks = wkb.Sheets(sheetname)
    therow = firstrow
    usedrow = True
    affrows = 0
    While usedrow
        thedate = wks.Cells(therow, 1)
        If thedate <> "" Then
            firstdate = wks.Cells(therow, 2)
            lastdate = wks.Cells(therow, 3)
            If lastdate < firstdate Then
                Rows(therow + 1).Insert shift:=xlShiftDown
                wks.Cells(therow + 1, 1) = thedate + 1
                wks.Cells(therow + 1, 2) = "0:00"
                wks.Cells(therow + 1, 3) = lastdate
                wks.Range(Cells(therow + 1, firstcopycolumn), Cells(therow + 1, lastcopycolumn)).Value = wks.Range(Cells(therow, firstcopycolumn), Cells(therow, lastcopycolumn)).Value
                wks.Cells(therow, 3) = "23:59"
                affrows = affrows + 1
            End If
            therow = therow + 1
        Else
            usedrow = False
        End If
    Wend
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    themessage = MsgBox("Finished" & vbCrLf & "Affected rows: " & affrows, vbInformation)
End Sub
```

To use Macros follow this [guide](https://superuser.com/questions/801609/how-do-i-add-vba-in-ms-office) or simply open VBA/ Macros with ALT+ F11, under *ThisWorkbook* insert a new module and paste the code.

The variable `firstrow` can be adjusted to your needs.

Also, with the help of the variables `firstcopycolumn` and `lastcopycolumn` you can define which range of columns will be copied down.

Comment: (1) The question says, "there are other columns in the rows that I'd like to simply copy down."  Your code doesn't do that, does it?  (2) Our standard Super User in-house VBA reference is [How do I add VBA in MS Office?](http://superuser.com/q/801609/150988)

Comment: @Scott (1) Updated to copy a range of columns. Thanks for the reference to (2).

Comment: Thanks for your time and effort into helping me with this. I solved it by copying someone's vba code to create a blank row under each identified row. Then I copied functions down using a filter. It took excel a long time to process the filtered copy down b/c I have 160k rows, but it worked. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a specific reason for wanting to do this in VBA? 
I solved [a similar problem](https://superuser.com/q/938355/150988) a few months ago using formulas;
I have adapted that solution to your problem.

But first, let me make sure that I understand your problem. 
As I understand it, you have a worksheet that looks like this:

```
       A          B       C       D       E         F
1   Date        Start    End    User    Color   Overnight
2   5/28/2015   15:00   21:00   Fred    Green
3   6/1/2015    16:25    1:00   Henry   Red     1
4   6/4/2015     9:00   13:00   Mary    Blue
```

where each row represents an event, with a date, start time, end time,
and other data.  Some of the events occur overnight
(i.e., they begin before midnight and end after midnight). 
You have marked those events with a `1` in Column `F`
(although there’s no need to do this manually;
you could simply set `F2` to `=B2>C2` and drag down). 
No event lasts more than 24 hours, so there’s no possibility
of an event starting at 10:00 on Monday and ending at 11:00 on Tuesday
(or, if there is, you have some way of identifying those events
that you haven’t described, and you have set Column `F` appropriately). 
In any case, no event spans more than two days
(e.g., you will never have an event beginning at 23:00 on Monday
and running until 1:00 on Wednesday). 
You want to split each multi-day (i.e., overnight) event into two rows:
one on the first day, from the start time until midnight (or 23:59),
and another on the second day, from midnight until the end time. 
You want all the other data associated with the event to be replicated
on both rows.  So, for the above data, you want

```
       A          B       C       D       E
1   Date        Start    End    User    Color
2   5/28/2015   15:00   21:00   Fred    Green
3   6/1/2015    16:25   23:59   Henry   Red
4   6/2/2015     0:00    1:00   Henry   Red
5   6/4/2015     9:00   13:00   Mary    Blue
```

as a result.

#### My Solution:

I will assume that you use no more than 23 columns,
so Columns `X`, `Y`, and `Z` are available for use as “helper columns”.

- Create a new sheet. 
  Assume that the existing sheet is `Sheet1` and the new sheet is `Sheet2`. 
  The following steps will copy the data from `Sheet1` to `Sheet2`,
  splitting rows.
- Copy the column headings from `Sheet1`, row 1, to `Sheet2`, row 1.
- Enter `=INDEX(Sheet1!A:A, $X2)+$Y2` into `Sheet2!A2`.
- Enter `=IF($Y2=0, INDEX(Sheet1!B:B, $X2), 0)` into `Sheet2!B2`.
- Enter `=IF(AND($Y2=0,$Z2>0), TIME(23,59,59), INDEX(Sheet1!C:C, $X2))` into `Sheet2!C2`.
- Enter `=INDEX(Sheet1!D:D, $X2)` into `Sheet2!D2`
  and drag/fill to the right to cover all your data
  (i.e., to column `E`, in my example).
- Copy `Sheet1:A2:E2` and paste formats (and column widths, if desired)
  onto `Sheet2:A2:E2`.
- Enter `2` in `Sheet2!X2`. 
  This designates the row on `Sheet1` that *this* row (on `Sheet2`)
  will pull data from.
- Enter `0` in `Sheet2!Y2`.
- Enter `=INDEX(Sheet1!F:F, $X2)` into `Sheet2!Z2`. 
  This creates a local copy of the “overnight” indicator.
- Select `Sheet2!A2:Z2` and drag/fill down to row 3.
- Change `Sheet2!X3` to `=IF(AND(Y2=0,Z2>0), X2, X2+1)`.
- Change `Sheet2!Y3` to `=IF(AND(Y2=0,Z2>0), Y2+1, 0)`.
- Select `Sheet2!A3:Z3` and drag/fill down as far as you need
  to get all your data.

It should look something like this:

```
       A          B       C       D       E                          X   Y   Z
1   Date        Start    End    User    Color
2   5/28/2015   15:00   21:00   Fred    Green                        2   0   0
3   6/1/2015    16:25   23:59   Henry   Red                          3   0   1
4   6/2/2015     0:00    1:00   Henry   Red                          3   1   1
5   6/4/2015     9:00   13:00   Mary    Blue                         4   0   0
```

Notes:

- As stated in the instructions, `Sheet2!Xn` specifies
  the row on `Sheet1` that row *`n`* (on `Sheet2`) will pull data from.
- `Sheet2!Yn` is a one-up number
  within a `Sheet2!Xn` value; i.e., within a `Sheet1` row; i.e., within an event. 
  For an overnight event, `Y` will be 0 for the pre-midnight segment and 1 for the post-midnight segment. 
  For example, since rows 3 and 4 on `Sheet2` pull data from`Sheet1` row 3,
  we have `X3`=`X4`=3, and `Y3`, `Y4` = 0, 1.

To make this permanent, you can copy and paste values,
and delete columns `X`, `Y`, and `Z`.

Comment: Thanks for your time and effort into helping me with this. I solved it by copying someones vba code to create a blank row under each row that identified. Then I functions down using a filter. It took excel a long time to process the filtered copy down b/c I have 160k rows, but it worked.

Comment: Well, if the code you used is significantly different from jcbermu's, why not post it as an answer (giving appropriate credit to the original author, of course)?

Answer (score -1):

I would create 3 new columns first. Use an excel formula to calculate your new data base on your original columns. Then take the 3 new columns, CUT and PASTE to the bottom of your first 3 columns.